# Updating theme resets theme options settings and widgets

Tags: themes

After updating my theme by removing the theme's folder and adding the one of the new theme's version, some themes options settings (link color in particular) have been reseted. Why? Aren't these settings exclusively database-determined?

Comment: For a definitive answer, you will probably have to look at how that specific theme handles things.

Comment: The theme settings are database driven, they are usually stored in wp_options table and are stored/retrieved using WordPress Options API. If you are missing the color setting after uploading new version of the same theme, then chances could be that the new version may have changed the option key using which the option is saved/retrieved. Please check the theme documentation or get in touch with the theme author who can assist you in better manner.

Comment: Thanks. I realize I also changed to different themes before managing to finally make the new version of the initial theme work. I guess that's the more likely cause?